# How do I match a substring that terminates at the end of the string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have this string, which is the name of a file I would like to rename:

`Planet.Earth.01.From.Pole.to.Pole.2006.1080p.HDDVD.x264.anoXmous_.mp4`

I would like to strip the portion from 2006 onwards. I thought to try searching for the index of the irrelevant portion and stripping it out with JavaScript string methods but that wouldn't work for other variable length files. How can I do this idiomatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there would only be one occurrence of `2006` in the filename, you may try a regex replacement:

```js
var filename = "Planet.Earth.01.From.Pole.to.Pole.2006.1080p.HDDVD.x264.anoXmous_.mp4";
console.log(filename);
filename = filename.replace(/\.?2006.*(\.[^.]+)$/, "$1");
console.log(filename);
```

The strategy here is to match from `2006` onwards, also capturing the final extension of the filename.  Then, we replace with just that extension.  We also capture a leading `.` in front of 2006, it it exists, to make sure that the replacement does not have two consecutive `.` separators in it.

```
\.?         match an optional leading dot (to avoid replacement with two consecutive dots)
2006        match "2006"
.*          consume everything until
(\.[^.]+)   capturing the file extension
$           end of the string
```

Comment: it works. thanks. care to explain the regex please?